# Perl algorithm compare arrays

Tags: perl

I have a question with my algorithm in Perl programming and I can't figure it out how to manage.

I have a database in a text file with some columns and many rows. I already could read all variables and save it into a multi-dimensional array. Let's presume its like this

```
 1.  Jack  A  math
 2.  John  A+ math
 3.  Jack  B  sports
 4. .
 5. .
 6. .
```

You can see there are four columns (id  name  grade lesson)

Now my question is, I want all rows with the same name exported to a new text file. I already have the algorithm idea that I can check row number one and compare it to all other rows blow and if there was a similarity rows export them and then check row number two and compare it with all other below rows and if there was similarity export it and so on.

Is it the right algorithm that I have in mind or is there any other algorithm for doing this?

I will be appreciate if you can give me a code example or any other further steps I can take.

I want this result for my example

```
1. Jack A for math, B in sports
2. John A+ for math
```

Comment: You don't want an array, you want a hash. Hash are key-value pairs. and so are really quite good or this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is homework, so I will give you a solution that you can use as hints to write your own answer. If you have problems with understanding it then please ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
  my ($id, $name, $grade, $lesson) = split;
  push @{ $data{$name} }, [ $grade, $lesson ];
}

my $n;
for my $name (sort keys %data) {
  my $grades = $data{$name};
  printf "%2d. %s %s\n", ++$n, $name, join ', ', map "$_->[0] in $_->[1]", @$grades;
}

__DATA__
1.  Jack  A  math
2.  John  A+ math
3.  Jack  B  sports
```

**output**

```
 1. Jack A in math, B in sports
 2. John A+ in math
```